# How to reload modules on both webpack-dev-server and express server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to remove Grunt from a project that uses both Grunt and Webpack for dev server and building a React App. I have successfully moved all of Grunt's tasks to Webpack, except for reloading the express server whenever there's a change on the server side code.

HMR works fine on the front end, I am invoking the webpack-dev-server from inside my Express backend and linking them with the WDS proxy, I haven't found a way to reload ONLY the server side code without compiling the React app.

I tried using nodemon to watch the backend code while listening to nodemon.on('start', loadWebpackHere) to call webpack only on server start (not restarts), it does watch the server files, but the start event is triggered on too, so the bundling process is still running.

I thought I could try creating a new webpack entry for the backend server, but I am not sure if it's possible to run both servers like that.

I haven't found any articles or samples on how to achieve this, has anybody set up something similar successfully?

Comment: [`webpack-hot-server-middleware'](https://github.com/60frames/webpack-hot-server-middleware) might be what you're after. Or at least the docs might help explain one approach to server side bundles

Comment: Unfortunately I tried a lot of different configurations, but the problem with using the middleware is still that if the API watcher triggers a restart, it would also rebuild the app. It's funny that you commented on this one today, literally minutes after I found my own solution (which I just posted) below.

EDIT: I got the notification today, but you posted yesterday*

Comment: yeah `webpack-hot-server-middleware` is only designed to hot reload a webpack bundle -- seems like `nodemon` is a common approach to 'hot' reloading the API although I think it can become problematic as your server grows and potentially becomes slower to startup. I was looking at https://github.com/glenjamin/ultimate-hot-reloading-example which watches the file system and invalidates the require.cache which is an interesting approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to enable HMR and also watch the API files with webpack only without triggering the UI build on API changes, but it was easy enough with a simple bash script to wrap around my app (took me months to get here, though):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [$NODE_ENV = "testing"] || [$NODE_ENV = "production"] ; then
    node api/server.js
else
    node_modules/.bin/nodemon --watch api api/server.js &
    node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server
fi
```

There's probably a better way, by adding the API as a webpack entry, but this one serves me just fine.

Comment: by running `nodemon` in background mode, how do you close it easily later?